# How to strip_tags all tags from 0 to 300 chars and from 301 to allow only some tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

I was wondering how on a given post that contains HTML also, to

```
strip_tags($entry->description);
```

from char 0 to 300 and from 301 to end of post allow only `<b><p><br>`

```
strip_tags($entry->description, '<b><p><br>');
```

I am looking for a way that does not kill performance though, because I want the page to load fast.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to create a leader text blurb?

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand your question. English is not my main language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just strip_tags() the two parts separately:

```
$start = strip_tags(substr($entry->description, 0, 300));
$rest = strip_tags(substr($entry->description, 300), '<b><p><br>');
$start . $rest;
```

Comment: Of note is that this may result in HTML snippets if, say, a tag starts before index 300 and ends after it.

Comment: This is true and I am dealing with it right now. Is there a way to handle this ?

Comment: @Jeksiliki: You'd have to massage the string via DOM to find an appropriate breaking point. Don't use string-based operations for it, as you're likely to leave dangling tags, e.g. `<div><ul><li>yada yada300char boundary here ->.<-` and chop off the closing `</li></ul></div>`.